# build.xml ant script condition

Tags: ant, build

Im trying to add a condition in my build.xml script for my deployment process. I basically need to determine the remote.host and based on the host set a variable value.

```
 <condition property="my-prop" value="production">
    <based on host=1234>
 </condition>
 <condition property="my-prop" value="development">
    <based on host=5678>
 </condition>
```

any ideas? of how the  is suppose to be?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, guessing you will have to tweak a bit based on machine addresses or environment or whatever.  Sets the value of my-prop to specified value based on test against the host property.

```
<!-- <property name="host" value="1234"/> -->
<property name="host" value="5678"/>

<target name="test">
    <condition property="my-prop" value="production">
        <equals arg1="1234" arg2="${host}"/>
    </condition>    
    <condition property="my-prop" value="development">
        <equals arg1="5678" arg2="${host}"/>
    </condition>

    <echo>${my-prop}</echo>
</target>
```